# Unable to generate broker.id when running secure Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I am attempting to run a Kafka cluster of 3 machines with SASL (via Kerberos) authentication. The first node starts up fine, and creates all the relevant Zookeeper nodes (/brokers, /consumers, etc).

However, no other brokers can successfully start due to authentication issues on those znodes. Specifically, I see the following exceptions causing the other brokers to fail on start up:

`[2016-06-15 22:27:04,365] DEBUG Reading reply sessionid:0x355561ae10f0008, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 13,5  replyHeader:: 13,4294967436,-102  request:: '/brokers/seqid,,-1  response::   (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-06-15 22:27:04,372] ERROR Failed to generate broker.id due to  (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /brokers/seqid
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException.create(ZkException.java:68)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.retryUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:1000)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.writeDataReturnStat(ZkClient.java:1147)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getSequenceId(ZkUtils.scala:799)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getBrokerSequenceId(ZkUtils.scala:214)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.generateBrokerId(KafkaServer.scala:677)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.getBrokerId(KafkaServer.scala:653)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:187)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:37)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /brokers/seqid
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:113)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.setData(ZooKeeper.java:1270)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.writeDataReturnStat(ZkConnection.java:138)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient$13.call(ZkClient.java:1151)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.retryUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:990)
        ... 9 more`

I can see these brokers authenticating to kerberos earlier in the log.

If I get the acl for `/brokers/seqid`, it only has `cdrwa` permissions for the one kafka broker which is successfully running:

`getAcl /brokers/seqid
'world,'anyone
: r
'sasl,'kafka_stage/running.kafka.node@REALM
: cdrwa`

I'm sure I configured something wrong, but I searched far and wide for someone with the same issue and came up short. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Tom. Did you resolve the issue ? I have the same problem. The answer provided seems to not be complete since, as far I understand, you used the same principal with a different fqdn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, it turns out they mentioned it in the [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_authz) - `It is necessary to have the same principal name across all brokers.`